# React-localstorage not available in another component unless i refresh page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am working on react js.using localstorage.setitem in one component & localStorage.getItem in another component .whenver i click a button i can see in browser developertools>Application localstorage is changing but that is reflected in another component.

Pls help me out!!correct me or give any suggestions to tackle this.

```js
_______________________________________________________________________

This is my startdate component
__________________________________________________________________________

export default class StartDatePicker1 extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      date: new Date(localStorage.getItem("StartDate")),
      // date: new Date(localStorage.getItem("StartDate")),
    }
  }

  onChange = (date) => {
    this.setState({
      date
    })
    const mnth = ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
    const day = ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
    const year = date.getFullYear();
    const hours = date.getHours();
    const minutes = date.getMinutes();
    var rohith = (year + "-" + mnth + "-" + day + " " + hours + ":" + minutes);
    // var rohith = [date.getFullYear(), mnth, day].join("-");
    localStorage.setItem("StartDate", rohith)
    // window.location.reload()
  }
  // componentDidMount(){
  //   localStorage.setItem("StartDate",localStorage.getItem("StartHour"))
  // }
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevState.date != this.state.date) {
      const mnth = ("0" + (this.state.date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
      const day = ("0" + this.state.date.getDate()).slice(-2);
      const year = this.state.date.getFullYear();
      const hours = this.state.date.getHours();
      const minutes = this.state.date.getMinutes();
      var rohith = (year + "-" + mnth + "-" + day + " " + hours + ":" + minutes);
      localStorage.setItem("StartDate", rohith)
    }
    console.log("method is called")
  }
  render() {
    console.log(localStorage.getItem("StartHour"))
    console.log(localStorage.getItem("StartDate"))
    console.log(this.state.date);

    return ( <
      div >
      <
      DateTimePicker onChange = {
        this.onChange
      }
      value = {
        this.state.date
      }
      /> < /
      div >
    );
  }
```

```html
____________________________________________________________________________

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

```js
______________________________________________________________________
my lifecycle component
_______________________________________________________________________

export default class LineLifeCycle extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            startdate:localStorage.getItem("StartDate"),
            Eff: [],
            Tech: [],
            Target: [],
            Mode: []
        }
    }
    // componentWillUpdate(prevProps,prevState) {
    //     // localStorage.getItem("StartDate")
    //     if(prevProps.startdate != this.state.startdate)
    //     {
    //         this.setState({startdate:localStorage.getItem("StartDate")})
    //     }
    // }
    
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log(localStorage.getItem("StartDate"))
        axios.post('http://localhost:35055/api/t/MachineOptHome/lifecycleByline', {
            PLId: 1,
            PUId: 1,
            StartTime: this.state.startdate,
            EndTime: localStorage.getItem("EndDate"),
        })
            .then((response) => {
                this.setState({ Eff: response.data });
                console.log(response.data);

            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
            this.forceUpdate();
    }
    componentDidUpdate(){
        this.componentDidMount();
    }
_______________________________________________________________________________
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Insufficient details. I suggest you make a codesandbox sample.

Comment: Please add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your question so other users can see what you're trying to do.

Comment: @SILENT can u help me now.i have added the code

Answer (score 1):

You can't see localstorage changes automatically. I understand that you are expecting your other component to re-render after setting the item in localstorage. But unfortunately React doesn't work that way

`A Component will only re-render if you change the props/state`

Localstorage is not a part of your react component tree. As a result you can't expect to see the changes in localstorage reflected upon in your component.

What you can do is try to save the value in some global state or pass it as props to other component.

Comment: You could also listen to the `storage` event and check if the localstorage value differs from the previous, and update some state accordingly to re-render: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/storage_event

Comment: The storage event only fires on other open tabs on the same domain, not the current tab. This will not work for OPs desired result